# Show last 5 posts from specific category (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to show the last 5 posts from a specific category, which will be linked to a function so I can insert the shortcode in a Wordpress page. The code I have is as below, it does everything I need (although I want to add featured image too) except it does not show posts from a specific category.

I've tried numerous things, but cannot find a working fix.

```
function Last5posts()
{
    $args = array( "showposts" => 5, "category" => 3 ); 
    $content = "";   

    query_posts($args);

    if ( have_posts() ) : 

        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            $link = get_permalink();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $date = get_the_date();                              

            $content .= "<div class='latest-posts'>";
            $content .= "<h3><a href='$link' target='_top'>$title / $date</a </h3>\n";
            $content .= "<p class='excerpt'>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
            $content .= "</div>";

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query(); 

     endif;

     return $content;
}

add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

I have tried replacing lines 3 and 4 with the code below, but it throws an error "syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 31".

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use code just like below

```
query_posts( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=5' );
```

using this wordpress by default will use last 5 post after this code...

Answer (score 2):

Use this
$catnames[1] denotes which category u want to use related to that post.

```
<?php $catnames = get_the_category();  
$postcatid=$catnames[1]->term_id;

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$postcatid.'&posts_per_page=4' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    </h3>
</li>
</ul>
 <?php endwhile; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [query posts parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Category_Parameters); you should definitely using "cat" instead of category.
Also, are you ending your "while" with an "endwhile;"? 
What does your complete code now look like?

Comment: I'm using the code below which i've added as an answer; it works, but also seems to show the "Leave a reply" box, which it shouldn't as the page i've put the shortcode on has comments disabled.